# write stderr and stdout to file without wrapper script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, file-descriptor

I want to redirect stderr and stdout to a file inside my bash script *myscript.sh* where some sub-processes are run.
The easiest way is to write a wrapper script *start_myscript.sh* that calls `myscript.sh 2>&1 > logfile` or `myscript.sh &> logfile`.

I wonder if it is possible to redirect both stderr and stdout inside *myscript.sh* to a logfile without using a wrapper script?
Fot this I opened a new file descriptor 3 and redirected stderr and stdout to fd3 which I redirect to /tmp/logfile.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3> /tmp/logfile
exec 1>&3
exec 2>&3
doing_something &
doing_other_things &
```

Both functions are doing something and producing output to stderr or stdout. The thing is they are working simultaneously and sometimes writing at the same time to stdout/stderr.
In this case a sentence from the first function is interrupted, then follows an output from the second one and finally follows the last part of the sentence from the first function. That breaks any log file...

So I thought of FIFO named pipes as it should be blocking and did a short test:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIPE=/tmp/mypipe
mkfifo $PIPE

cat LONGTEXTFILE > $PIPE &
ls -la /usr/bin > $PIPE &
ls -la /tmp > $PIPE &
```

The test is simple. I create a named pipe $PIPE, cat a long text file over some seconds to stdout which is redirected to the named pipe. I'm doing this in the background while short calls of `ls` redirect its output to the named pipe. This should simulate output from different functions running at once in the background.

In another terminal I opened the named pipe with
`cat /tmp/mypipe`

My assumption was that the FIFO named pipe is blocked while it gets input from `cat` and stdout from `ls` would wait until stdout from cat ends.

Unfortunately the result is disappointing. Output from `ls` is placed somewhere in the middle of the output from `cat`, not afterwards.
Have I done any mistakes?

Is there any other way to redirect stderr/stdout from inside a script to a logfile without using a wrapper script?

Comment: **exec** is correctly used in your sample code... But stdout and stderr are streams, and if you redirect them to the same stream and execute several simultaneous write operations, the output of those different writes will be intermingled. That's inherent to streams.

Comment: You're probably confusing `2>&1 > logfile` with `> logfile 2>&1`.

Comment: @Cyrus You're right! This should be `myscript.sh > logfile 2>&1`. A good explanation I found at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

@Jean-LoupSabatier Yes I think I get stuck here and there is no other solution than to use a wrapper script? Right?
But what's different to wrapper scripts that collect simultaneous streams from threads correctly and not intermingled?